# TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html error when django+react app deployed to Heroku

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, deployment, whitenoise

I created a simple django & react app (which just loads react default page for now) and I am trying to deploy to Heroku. When I run `python manage.py runserver` on localhost it runs fine (with default react page showing), but when I deploy it to Heroku, I get the following error:

`TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html`

This is the site : https://temp-app-test.herokuapp.com/

I'm pretty sure I included `index.html` in templates using `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')` in `settings.py`, but it doesn't work. I also included `"postinstall": "npm run build"` in `scripts` in `package.json` file.

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.6
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.0.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.4
```

Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn test_test_test.wsgi --log-file -
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for test_test_test project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.10.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'test_test_test.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'test_test_test.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'),
]
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_test_test.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I've been stuck here for hours, and I would like some help on this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],` into `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public')],`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've found that i didn't add buildpacks for heroku/nodejs. Now it is working!